# Почему не запускается change, когда устанавливаю val()?

Tags: jquery, select, триггер, onchange

Через URL ко мне приходят параметры со значениями, которые я записываю в массив **paramsURL[]**.
Тогда мне нужно установить пришедшие данные как *value для select*.

```
$('select[name="mtype"]').val(paramsURL['mtype']);
```

После чего val() срабатывает верно, но событие change для select не запускается.
Погуглив, нашел триггер для имитации изменения ->

```
trigger('change')
```

Но он никакого действия не дает. Еще пробовал **onchange();** - тоже никакого результата. Работает только при клике мышкой или enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установка скриптом значений элементов пользовательского ввода данных не приводит к автоматическому вызову события `change`.

```js
$('#test').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$("#valueOnly").click(function(){
  var old = $('#test').val();
  $('#test').val((old != 2)? 2 : 3);
});

$("#valueAndChange").click(function(){
  var old = $('#test').val();
  $('#test').val((old != 2)? 2 : 3);
  $('#test').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<button id="valueOnly">Set value only</button>
<button id="valueAndChange">Set value and trigger change</button>
```

Comment: Да, действительно забыл событие указать.. Спасибо!
Из этого вывод - если хочешь, чтобы оно работало при загрузке, то обернуть в событие $.load(); верно?!

Comment: @KobetsMatviy Так, подождите. Какой `load`? К чему он относится? Имеет смысл задать отдельный вопрос, с показом соответствующего кода.

Comment: Да нет же. Здесь все верно)) Я имею ввиду, если я не хочу кликать на элемент для отработки кода. А сразу же при загрузке реализовать. Тогда использовать **load** ?!

Comment: @KobetsMatviy я не понимаю, о каком `load` идет речь. Вы `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` имеете в виду?

Comment: Именно, только у него же есть брат .load(function() {...}); который работает до загрузки DOM. А вообще да, попутал.